# Why can't a field name and a variable have same name?

Tags: java, netbeans

I changed the variable name of a text field to name, then I wrote this in Netbeans IDE

`

```
 /**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    name = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    name.setText("jTextField1");
    name.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            nameActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(127, 127, 127)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addContainerGap(200, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(95, 95, 95)
            .addComponent(name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(144, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

String name=name.getText();
    System.out.println(name);// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void nameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
 }                                    

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ss.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ss.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ss.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ss.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ss().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JTextField name;
// End of variables declaration
```

}`

There is an error when I declared String name=name.getText();
The error was "Cannot find symbol: Method getText"
Why did this happen and what are the ways to correct it?

Comment: At that point you've already said t1 is no longer a text field, but a String, and a String has no such method getText()

Comment: Understood, Thanks for helping

Comment: *"I changed the variable name of a text field to t1"* Why the hell did you do that? You should rename identifiers to something that is **more** readable, not less!

Comment: I could have named it "Name", then the same error would have popped up If I also declared `String Name=Name.getText();` @TimothyTruckle

Comment: *"I could have named it "Name""* which is not intentional either because it is the *input* for the name, so it should be `nameInput`...

Comment: A lot people, including myself, read Stack Overflow at work.  Please consider editing your profile and choosing a better user name, one that I don’t have to worry about other people seeing on my screen.

Comment: What was `Name`, a non-convention-compliant variable name, defined as prior to the one single line of code you showed us? If it wasn't already defined then that line will not compile. Depending on where it was defined before, the line still might not compile. It's usually best not to declare the same variable name for different things. And it's good to adhere to the Java naming conventions. And when asking questions, advisable not to withhold information such as the relevant code.

Comment: @LewBloch Edited The question Thanks for pointing out the error

Comment: @VGR I never thought about that, thanks for the suggestion.I will change to a better username, you can also suggest a good username.

Comment: @Swastika, my comment still stands. I don't know what you "edited", but the flaws were not addressed. At all.

Comment: @LewBloch Edited again Hope it is correct now

Comment: Well, you still need to study the naming conventions (`ss` is not conventional for a type name), but it's better. The root of your actual problem is that you still use the same variable name for two different things. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the method *getText()* from the variable *t1*, which is of type String. String class doesn't have that method defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can have a local variable with the same name as a field. But once the variable is declared, it *shadows* the field and you need to use `this` to reference it:

```
String Name = this.Name.getText();
```

Note: Java convention is for all variable names (besides constants) to begin with a lowercase character.

Answer (score -1):

This is how the computer sees it.

Create a `String` variable called `t1` and save into it the text value of a different variable also called `t1`.

You cannot assign the variable itself because the program hasn't fully executed that line of code yet. It does't know what `t1` is.

I think this is what you were looking to do, but it will not work still because `String` has no method for `.getText()`

```
String t1 = "Hello";
String t2 = t2.getText(); // t2 will now have whatever t1 was saved with.
```

Comment: Right you are. I'm deleting the comment.